# Java HashMap.get() is returning null on valid key

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hashmap, objectmapper

I've `Constant.g()` static function describe below:

```
public class Constant {

    private static Properties constantConfig;

    public static String g(String property) {
        try {
            if(constantConfig == null) {
                constantConfig = new Properties();
                constantConfig.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" +
                        "constants.properties"));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return constantConfig.getProperty(property);
    }

}
```

I've a json and I convert that into map like below:

```
Map data = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(json, HashMap.class);
```

Then I observe following behavior:

```
Constant.g("user_id") // this returns String "userId" successfully

data.get("userId") // This also works fine and return value correctly
```

but below code returns `null`:

```
data.get(Constant.g("user_id"))
```

This might be `equal()` and `HashCode()` problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: `String` implements `equals()` and `hashcode()` correctly, so it has nothing to do with that. What you describe cannot happen with the code shown (the last 2 snippets).

Comment: Then what else it can be ?

Comment: Does `"userId".equals(Constant.g("user_id"))` return `true`?

Comment: Check it with debugger first. I bet Constat.g("user_id") did not returned in your case "userId" or data does not contain key "userId"

Comment: ..or there's whitespace, or a similar minor issue.

Comment: @4castle `"userId".equals(Constant.g("user_id"))` returns false. Can you guide a bit?

Comment: @Vicctor as I stated, it return `Constat.g("user_id")` returns `userId` correctly

Comment: @Kayaman I tried trim as well and it doesn't works

Comment: If it returns false, then it's not returning `userId` correctly. Try calling `.toCharArray()` on the strings and compare them more closely. There's probably some unprintable character.

Comment: @4castle as far as System.out.print() is concern, It's printing fine. I'll try your way.

Comment: "It's printing fine", but it's not working fine.

Comment: @4castle Thank you very much. Your `toCharArray()` helped in solving my problem. My `constants.properties` file sucks. Thank you once again. Please let me know if I can give you some point in anyway?